# Olympic artistic gymnastics: Why are not all subdisciplines open for both sexes

Tags: gymnastics

Olympic artistic gymnastics is maybe the only olympic sport, where men and women do almost totally [different subdisciplines](https://www.liveabout.com/womens-gymnastics-vs-mens-gymnastics-1714801) (except for vault and floor). For example women are not allowed to compete in gymnastics rings or pommel horse and men are not allowed to compete in beam.

Historically the reasons doesn't seem to be clear, I have read that "the 1936 Olympics, the first to include women, had just one set of gymnastic apparatuses, and women used some of them" [source](https://www.bustle.com/articles/178086-why-dont-female-gymnasts-do-rings-the-olympics-reinforce-these-outdated-gender-roles-in-a-surprising) and in the 48 Olympics women seemed to compete in rings.

According to [this source](https://www.bustle.com/articles/178086-why-dont-female-gymnasts-do-rings-the-olympics-reinforce-these-outdated-gender-roles-in-a-surprising)

> Very informed speculation suggests that it was a combination of
> women's physical attributes and gender norms that contributed to the
> apparatus selection.

From a modern perspective, I don't see any reasons not to open all subdisciplines for both women and men. It might (surely) be that men can aquire higher skills for example on gymnastic rings or on pommel horse than women (because of higher upper body strength), but that's equally the case in many other sports as well for example in weightlifting or crossfit.

I think, that it might be very difficult to train for all of the union of sets of the the existing disciplines, however this don't have to be required. For example in track and field most athletes specialize on one (or a few) subdisciplines.

This leads me to the following questions:

- Are there documented discussions about this topic on any international or national level? Do you have references?
- If so, what where the reasons not to open all subdisciplines for both sexes?
- Where there any "experimental" attempts in the past to go a step into this direction?

Footnote

Just as addition here some links to youtube-videos of some example how it may look like:

- Women on rings: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtDkYvwH94U), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXPyCFPzi_k), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6PVQULwvSA)
- Men on beam and uneven bars: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_Oz5_jmgkk)

(It is difficult to find such examples).